# How to add path so python can find a program?

Tags: python, sqlite, path

I'm trying to use `sqlite` with python via the `import` function, but it looks that python can't find `sqlite`.

My sys.path contains the following:

```
['', '/usr/local/share/python', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.26-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

But `sqlite` is listed in `usr/lib`.

Edit:
As suggested, I tried `import sqlite3`, but python returns this error:

```
dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
  Reason: image not found
```

How do I load `sqlite`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add anything to your module search path; the SQLite module comes with the Python standard library. However, you misspelled the name of the module, it is called [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) (note the `3` on the end):

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct 22 2012, 06:12:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
<sqlite3.Connection object at 0x105354200>
```

If you get errors still, your homebrew installation is broken; you probably ran into [this bug](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/17312). Run:

```
brew rm sqlite python
brew install python
```

to repair.

Comment: Thanks - Tried that, but got an error message.  Updated the post with the error message.

Comment: @mikebmassey: Right, that is a homebrew bug, instructions to fix included.

Answer (score 0):

[sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) is the name of the python module which provides an interface between Python and the sqlite database engine. [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is the name of the underlying database engine.

So (as Martijn Pieters already pointed out) try:

```
import sqlite3
```